# Alexa, unable to link smart home skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am trying to link my smart home skill to my OAuth 2.0 server.

The error happens when I redirect the Access Token request to:

```
https://pitangui.amazon.com/api/skill/link/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX?access_token=b6bcd5a1870322898864d1a5284af5abac58d619&state=xyz&token_type=Bearer
```

I also tried:

```
https://pitangui.amazon.com/api/skill/link/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX#access_token=b6bcd5a1870322898864d1a5284af5abac58d619&state=xyz&token_type=Bearer
```

But the erros persist.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share what error you are getting?

Comment: The error is: We were unable to link embrace at this time. I followed the alexa documentation described here: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/link-an-alexa-user-with-a-user-in-your-system.html

And nothing works.

Comment: I discovered which was my error. I was redirecting the post request sent by Alexa service, but was to response the request with the token object.

Thanks for trying help me

Comment: @Thi I believe I have the same issue as you did

Comment: @ThiagoBarros. I believe I have the same issue as you did. I did not understand what your fix was. I'm doing the same things here - Click link account - takes me to a form where I need to enter credentials. I send the credentials back via POST to my node Server. Node authenticates, generates a code and redirects the response to Alexa. At the user end, I get an error message after a few seconds "We were unable to link MySkill at this time". Can you elaborate on "but was to response the request with token object". Thanks

Comment: @Pankaj, I return the request like that:

`response.status(httpStatus.OK)                
                .send({
                    "access_token": ${token.accessToken},
                    "token_type": "Bearer",
                    "expires_in": 3600,
                    "refresh_token": ${token.refreshToken}
                });`

Comment: @Pankaj, After you redirect the generated code to Alexa Server, It request an access token at the link that you informed in the alexa console. I just simple return the request  with the access token like that:

`response.status(httpStatus.OK)                
                .send({
                    "access_token": ${token.accessToken},
                    "token_type": "Bearer",
                    "expires_in": 3600,
                    "refresh_token": ${token.refreshToken}
                });`

Comment: Thanks @ThiagoBarros. That's the thing, I don't see Alexa requesting an access token from my server on the separate link I provided for access tokens. Any idea where I can look up logs on where exactly Alexa tries and fails to get the access token ?

Comment: @Pankaj, you must provide a access code URL and access token URL for Alexa account linking process. And about log, I have no if Alexa has it. If you find out please tell me, I'd like to know too.